# CosmosDB connection with mongodb and mongoose

Tags: mongoose, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to connect to my DB via mongoose like so:

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.COSMOSDB_CONNSTR, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.COSMODDB_USER,
      password: process.env.COSMOSDB_PASSWORD
    }
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connection to CosmosDB successful"))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I am getting an error saying:

> MongoError: database name must be a string

Now, if I remove `useNewUrlParser: true,`
I get:

> Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character

I don't want to remove useNewURLParser obviously, but I thought that was odd.

```
COSMOSDB_CONNSTR=mongodb://jedi:iamajediawhatareyou==@jedidb.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb
COSMODDB_USER=jediidb
COSMOSDB_PASSWORD=iamajediawhatareyou==
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was reading their docs and one spot shows that you need the dbname in front of  `?ssl=true`

So adjusting the string it actually will look like this.

```
COSMOSDB_CONNSTR=mongodb://jedi:iamajediawhatareyou==@jedidb.documents.azure.com:10255/jedi?ssl=true
```